# Updating asp.net application with jquery ajax, having difficulty with storing session variables

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have an asp.net application that I am updating to use JQuery Ajax calls to a web service that return JSON rather than having a gridview perform the rendering.

The contents of the grid are controlled by various radio buttons. Presently the application is set to perform a postback when a radio button is changed, store the selected value in the session and then rebind the data grid.

The values are held in the session so that the page will 'remember' the criteria used and reapply them if the user navigates to a separate page in the application and then navigates back to the grid.

I have amended the to use knockout js to handle all the data binding and presentation. The viewmodel calls an asmx web service that returns the JSON that needs to be displayed. So far so good.

I am however completely stuck as to where to set the session variables - When the JQuery Ajax call is made to the web service the web service has no current session so I can't store the variables here.

I don't think JQuery / JavaScript can save session variables so I'm a bit stuck.

Anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks

Chris

Comment: You can configure your web service to have access to session state.

Comment: Do you mean ASMX Web Service? Also what language do you use on the backend - c#?

Comment: I did - apologies, amended

Comment: Thanks Brad. Adding  <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> to my web method seems to have done the job.